# AngularJS getting rid of # symbol in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, apache

I'm trying to fix my app so that the URLs appear "/posts" instead of "/#/posts".  I did a bunch of research and now my app.js is configured as such:

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "app.controllers"]).

config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when("/", {
    templateUrl: "views/partials/postlist.html",
    controller: "IndexCtrl"
  }).
  when("/posts", {
    templateUrl: "views/partials/posttable.html",
    controller: "PostsCtrl"
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/"
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
  });
});
```

This fixes one half of the issue: the URLs appear in the browser without the "#" symbol.  However, if I type "localhost:3000/posts", I get a 404 with the message "cannot GET /posts."  What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I need to post any more sections of code.

Comment: You will need to also set up your server to understand how to respond to those requests.

Comment: I imagine you'll need to manually intercept anchor clicks and use the history api to rewrite the url without the browser requesting the page from the server, or add something like a htaccess to the server side

Comment: Hi, Patrick, well if you are using a nodeJS Server, try Vishnus answer, if not, try mine :-) cheers :-)

Comment: Chances are /posts is not being intercepted by any of your current route configuration on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Node.js server

```
app.set('views', path.normalize(__dirname) + '/app/views'); // set views folder path in express app
app.route('/*') // for all requests to your server
  .get(res.render('index')); //render index.html
```

For Apache Server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: ähm, I may be wrong, but is __dirname and express nodeJS and this post is about AngularJS?!?

Comment: @Neo "cannot GET /posts" response is given by node.js server. It should be configured in the server itself. see the comment of `Tom` below the question.

Comment: ?!? yes its from the server, but who said its a nodeJS Server? :-)

Comment: @Neo I have worked with apache, tomcat and node.js servers. `Cannot get XXX` response will be given by only node.js server if there is no route.

Comment: Thats not true, you will get this on any LAMP stack with AngularJS and the X

Comment: Just put a AngularJS App on any Webserver around the web, configure its route like explained above and then just call a <a href="/posts">... you will see it doesnt work

Comment: @Neo May be, I don't know that. can you share an `Lamp Stack with AngularJS` link here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85023/discussion-between-neo-and-vishnu).